# jquery ui (drag and drop component)

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-ui

http://www.edigitsoftware.com/formbuilder-v2/edit.php?id=8091

when drag any component that place make new component and drag component place value also post in PHP side and that value store in database

Comment: use can call ajax(php page store database ) after drop the component  .

Comment: done bro i can make click event component generate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Like Some Example**
drag any items after  Dropped items After call Function Drop Then Inside Function Call Ajax or some different function

```
$("#DropDivid").droppable({

    drop:function (event, ui) 
         {

              // Here Your Ajax Code  Store Value in Database
         }
   });
```

Comment: i want moveable controller like above like this also apply in MVC

Comment: bro you know any rich textarea editor and my requirement is this content also post with select tag also need

Comment: like when select bold  then write "THIS IS COOL"   when post in php that time i need "<b>THIS IS COOL</b>" i need this type if you know so please  tell me

Comment: Hauth how apply in codeigniter you know ???

Comment: no, sorry .  i am not use in codeigniter